# x_test and y_test from tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How to obtain x_test and y_test from the following code

```
  test_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
   data_dir2, labels ='inferred', label_mode='categorical',
    #validation_split=0.2,
    #subset="validation",
    #labels='inferred',
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=64)
```

Comment: why do you need it? maybe you should use directly `test_generator`?

Comment: For some reasons I need to use tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory, could please help me resolve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on documentation [image_dataset_from_directory-function](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#image_dataset_from_directory-function) - it may return tuples `(images, labels)` so you may try to use `for`-loop to create lists with `X` and `Y`

Because it returns values in some `EagerTensor` so I use `append()` to move to normal list.

```py
X = []
Y = []

for images, labels in test_generator:
    for image in images:
        X.append(image)                    # append tensor
        #X.append(image.numpy())           # append numpy.array
        #X.append(image.numpy().tolist())  # append list
    for label in labels:
        Y.append(label)                    # append tensor
        #Y.append(label.numpy())           # append numpy.array
        #Y.append(label.numpy().tolist())  # append list
```

If you use `label_mode='int'` then it gives `Y = [ 1, 0, 2 ]`
If you use `label_mode='categorical'` then it gives `Y = [ [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1] ]`

If you need strings with class names (and you use `label_mode='int'`):

```
Y = [test_generator.class_names[x] for x in Y]
```